# Exception in log: Analytics root item should exist in the database. Source: Sitecore.Marketing

Tags: exception, sitecore, analytics, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

After upgrading a 6.5 Sitecore solution to 8.1, starting with clean 8.1 databases and migrating the items from old solution, I am getting an exception in the logs complaining about Analytics root item missing. Checked in Sitecore and the Marketing Center and the 8.1 specific items exist. Any clue that is causing this exception?
Thank you in advance!

### Message: analytics root item should exist in the database

Source: Sitecore.Marketing
at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.Data.ItemDb.ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository..ctor(String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive, IDefinitionRecordMapper`1 mapper)
at Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.Data.ItemDb.ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository..ctor(String databaseName, Boolean assumeActive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is comming from:

```
  public ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository(string databaseName, bool assumeActive, IDefinitionRecordMapper<OutcomeDefinitionRecord> mapper)
  : base(Assert.ResultNotNull<Database>(Database.GetDatabase(databaseName), "database not found " + databaseName), ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository.OutcomeTemplateId, ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository.OutcomeContainerId, assumeActive, mapper)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) databaseName, "databaseName");
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) mapper, "mapper");
  this.itemDb = Assert.ResultNotNull<Database>(Database.GetDatabase(databaseName), "database not found " + databaseName);
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) this.itemDb, "item database '{0}' should be available", (object) databaseName);
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) this.itemDb.GetItem(ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository.OutcomeContainerId), "analytics root item should exist in the database");
}
```

Exception is thrown by this line :

```
 Assert.IsNotNull((object) this.itemDb.GetItem(ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository.OutcomeContainerId), "analytics root item should exist in the database");
```

You need to check if you have item with id:

```
 private static readonly ID OutcomeContainerId = Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.WellKnownIdentifiers.MarketingCenterOutcomeContainerId;
  public static readonly ID MarketingCenterOutcomeContainerId = ID.Parse("{062A1E69-0BF6-4D6D-AC4F-C11D0F7DC1E1}");
```

The item with above id is the item with path:

```
/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Outcomes
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad! Indeed, the master database did not contain the Outcomes and some other items. This is wierd as it's a clean restore from the 8.1 Initial Version. Something must've went wrong at some point.